# How to Fetch data from database by passing two numbers as parameters?

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

i want to get some data from my database by passing 2 values like

```
getdata("1","5");
```

My function in database and the id is stored as String in database.

```
getdata(String FromMember_id,String ToMember_id){

}
```

I have also cast the id to get data but I didnt get data

Query is

```
"SELECT * FROM MilkCollection WHERE cast(member_code as REAL) 
BETWEEN  '"+ FromMember_id + "' AND '" +ToMember_id+ "' ";
```

When is use this Query without casting

```
"SELECT * FROM MilkCollection WHERE member_code '"+ FromMember_id + "' 
AND '" + ToMember_id + "'"
```

and when i dont cast the member_code and do the same query it shows data but it shows the other data other id like 17,18,19 i guess its taking the starting value of 17,18,19 because there is 1 in starting of them.

Comment: You're passing strings, not ints. Please lear about DataTypes in general (Java), in SQL and in SQLite.

Comment: @Rotwang sir in starting i did that but it didn't worked. Even when i log the query there is no error in it sir.

Comment: You're also using strings in your query comparisons. And since in your table (at least, if the table is properly designed) they are integers, there'll be no match at all.

Comment: @Rotwang The id field (member_code) is string in the table milkcollection and by casting i changed in it into real as well as in int also and in parameters i passed strings and also integers values one by one but it didn't worked.

Comment: `The id field ... is string in the table` Then the table is designed improperly.

Comment: yea i know that in starting the database was like id should be "12Shob" so i have to take is as a string. thats the reason but now the id is stored as 1,2,3,4,5 and so on.

Comment: what is your `CREATE TABLE` statement?

Comment: @Rotwang this worked for me "SELECT * FROM MilkCollection WHERE  cast(member_code as REAL) >='"+ FromMember_id + "' AND cast(member_code as REAL) <= '" + ToMember_id + "' "; for me.

Comment: @pskink i was creating table with id(member_code) and name and other data and the member_code filed i took was string type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understand your issue, you need to type cast your passing values to `REAL` which sure gives you a workaround solutions.

```
"SELECT * FROM MilkCollection WHERE  cast(member_code as REAL) >='"+ FromMember_id + "' AND cast(member_code as REAL) <= '" + ToMember_id + "' ";
```

**Description:** Just because you are passing string values using your member function which causes uncertainty while fetching data from your database.

Comment: wc, happy to help .. :)

Comment: `"Just because you are passing string values ..."` it does not matter:  `SQLiteDatabase#rawQuery` or `SQLiteDatabase#query` takes ONLY string arguments in `selectionArgs` parameter

Comment: @pskink i appreciate your words here but op has clearly written inside his ques `when i don't cast the member_code as REAL` it works but shows some other data prefixed by 1 like 11, 12, 13 etc if the range is 1 to 5.

Comment: see http://pastebin.com/vdMH6isB, here 2, 4 200, 400 are passed to `rawQuery` as strings, since you can pass ONLY String array to that method

Comment: okay cool, here created number as `INT` `db.execSQL("create table t (number INT);");` but op has stored code id as `String`, this makes diff and forces to cast values please check.

Comment: so the solution is to create `(number INT)` as only numbers are inserted / queried, and not to use any workarounds with "REAL casts"

Comment: @pskink correct and regards your efforts, but i have gone through to the entire ques and comments before posted please see the sixth comment on ques.

Comment: `"but now the id is stored as 1,2,3,4,5 and so on"` so if IDs are integers the solution is to create integer column in the upgraded database

Answer (score 0):

Here is some working code for sending objects for a get. You can compare and see where you have taken a misstep.

```
public String getPreachLogString(long day, String time) {
    String selectQuery;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Cursor cursor;
    String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE day = " + day + " AND time = \"" + time + "\"";
    cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```

To use strings in search I wrap string in `\"` where you wrap in `'`. Not sure why you are storing member IDs as string, assuming you have letters involved, but try casting member_code as TEXT to make a logical comparison between the 2 objects.

What you are trying to accomplish is possible I do it all the time. You just need to compare properly.

```
public ArrayList<String> getMonthlyWork(int year, int month) {
    long thismonth = 0;
    long nextmonth = 0;
    String selectQuery;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    SimpleDateFormat formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US);

    String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(year, month, 1);
    thismonth = c.getTimeInMillis();
    if (month < 11) {
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month + 1);
    } else {
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year + 1);
    }
    nextmonth = c.getTimeInMillis();

    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE day >= " + thismonth + " AND day < " + nextmonth;
```

Comment: by casting casting member_code as TEXT this works but problem is it is reading only first value like example :- i want data of id between 1-5 it is showing of data of id's 11,12,13,14 so on because it is reading 11 id's first 1 in between 1-5 and so on brother.

Comment: that is the issue with Strings, unless you can do a `.length()` comparator to ensure 1 is 1 and not 11 and 2 is 2, not 21 or 22. but that would be done after the retrieval of the results

Answer (score 0):

Seems like John Bravdo already given you a working example

Let me address following 2 areas:
1. Why following SQL is not returning result?

Code:
"SELECT * FROM MilkCollection WHERE cast(member_code as REAL) 
BETWEEN  '"+ FromMember_id + "' AND '" +ToMember_id+ "' ";

With parameter value:
SELECT * FROM MilkCollection WHERE cast(member_code as REAL) 
BETWEEN  1 AND 5;

Answer: Your table does not has any record containing value 1 to 5, but it does has record with value 17, 18, 19.  Try pass the value 17 and 19 instead of 1 and 5, then it should return value.  Moreover, test the SQL in database directly to confirm it does return data before checking in your program

2. Poor performance

Using a function call on any indexed column, e.g. cast(member_code as REAL), will not able to make use of index (regular index).  Therefore, this SQL going to scan the entire table.  You will start to see poor performance as the table size grow.  Therefore, you need to use a column that is integer type in order to filter by integer value.  You can add this column later after you have bandwidth.  If the table is just a 1MB in disk, then you need to consider how many concurrent users are going to trigger this SQL call.  If there are 1000 users running it concurrently, then it will cause 1GB of disk I/O (although DB engine could cache it) and it will be slow as well

Comment: SingCheong Chen thanks for the reply actually database will be in particular   in the phone device for the single user and now i got the desired result by using vaibhav result below.